# Heroku - deploy app from another directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, heroku

I had the directory called `A` from which I deployed a Rails app to Heroku. Now, I moved this project on my localhost to another directory called `B` and from this `B` directory I would need to deploy the app to the origrinal Heroku app (to the same app where I deployed the code from `A` directory).

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to add the git repo url to `B`.

```
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:YOURAPPNAME.git
```

and `git push heroku master` would work.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you moved the `.git` directory together with the rest of the files, there should be no difference and everything should work as before. If you don't have the `.git` directory, you will have to set the remote heroku url again.